# How can I access my old Windows 7 RC partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

After installing Windows 7 RTM, my computer now skips the boot selection screen and so I am unable to access my Windows 7 RC partition currently.

Is there any way to access it again?

This is not for access to files as I can already access them from the RTM partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a live Linux CD like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), you should be able to access any files and folders on your system, assuming that they haven't been overwritten.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear but I am not wanting access to files, as I can very easily access them from my RTM partition.

Comment: I see. New answer added above/below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows still:

**XP**: right click my computer > propereties > advanced tab > startup and recovery section > settings button and at the top you can select from the various OS installs.

**Vista/7**: Control panel > system and maintenance > system > left column advanced system settings > startup and recovery section > settings button and at the top you can select from the various OS installs

Comment: Only "Windows 7" is in the list.